# Implement spring social with spring security + Jsf 2

Tags: spring, jsf-2, spring-security, spring-social

I've made a sample webapp with all these Framework :
JSF 2.2 (Primefaces / prettyfaces), Spring, Spring Security (with remember me), Spring JPA and Log4j2.
The  news is everything work well :)

Now i want to implement the last  framework  : Spring social
This is my task list :

- Enable connection with FaceBook, Twitter and google
- Allow users to have multi accounts (like stackoverflow)
- Secure socials connection
- Add remember me and social account disconnect

But ... i can't find how to do this (I try a lot of blog but no one really talk about it) and
I don't understand Spring social documentation and sample who come with it.

Is someone can help me (or purpose sample with this implementation) ?

The full project on github : https://github.com/cryosore/training

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: CrYoSoRe, did you get any solution. I think there is no direct way of handling JSF and spring security both as connectController etc are MVC based.

Answer (score 0):

Mohd Adnan, I find a way but not with spring social :)

First i've made some update in my model class :
I have a User class who store user account information (credential, roles, ...)

I added a Standard Account class who store extra information for standard auth (like password)

I added a Social Account class who store extra information for social auth (Id, provider, ...)

Like this i keep all security rules already implemented

I just have to do the last task and everything will work like i want ;)

Comment: and how is your idea to connect with providers?